# How to configure logback for package?

Tags: configuration, package, logback

Is it possible to configure logback to log at e.g. WARN or INFO level for all packages but x.y? And then separate configuration for package x.y only.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I don't know of any way you can get the "NOT" package aspect of your question, but I routinely log one package at DEBUG and all the rest at INFO and...above is it...WARN and ERROR.  This is straight up-the-middle logback.  My loggers are all like...

```
package rekdev.org.service.api;
public class DefaultConfigResource {
    // ...
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DefaultConfigResource.class );
    // ...
}
```

...on a logback.xml configuration like...

```
  <logger name="rekdev.org.service.api" level="debug" />
  ...
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="DAILY_ROLLING" />
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
  </root>
```

Has the effect of most output popping out at INFO, WARN, ERROR but all the rekdev.org.service.api classes.  All the classes in the rekdev.org.service.api package produce output at DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR.

Or did I misunderstand your questions entirely?

Comment: A logger should always be "*static* final" (shared across all instances of the logged class) as it's too expensive to have a separate logger instance for every instance of the logged class.

Comment: You'd have that in annotation on JavaConf ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999436/creating-a-logger-on-a-logback-java-based-no-xml-configuration